# inputs para parametrizar un group_by

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, r-dplyr

Estos intentando crea una agrupación dinámica con shiny en r mediante el uso de la librería dplyr y ya me funciona con el primer input pero al querer parametrizar el campo para el cálculo me da error ya que al parecer mi valor de input está llegando como texto y no como el tipo de dato que deberia. esto me ocurría con el primer parámetro pero lo solucione con el uso del .dots pero esto no me resulto en el según parámetro.

Si alguien puede ayudarme explicando que tipo de dato o como se debería indicar el segundo campo, ya que tal como está el código el input$text2 esta recibiendo el valor del input como un texto y no como un parámetro que indique el nombre del campo con el q debería realizar el promedio

```
values$df %>% group_by(.dots = input$text1) %>% summarise(promedio = mean(input$text2))
```

Comment: Mencionas un error, ¿podrías agregar el texto completo? saludos.

Comment: Más allá de la pregunta hay otro problema con tu código: al usar `$` estás extrayendo vectores y `dplyr` funciona con `data.frame` y nombres de columna desnudos (sin comillas). Para tu problema podrías consultar https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html . Con un ejemplo completo y reproducible seguramente consigas aquí ayuda sobre como solucionar el problema usando evaluación no estándar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Va una respuesta al título de la pregunta (parametrizar group_by).

## Problema

`dplyr` usa evaluación no estándar. Esto permite usar nombres de columna sin comillas y armar  o listas vectores sin usar `c()`, cosa que produciría un error si se hiciera la evaluación estándar de R. Al hacerlo se pierde la transparencia referencial de R, de acuerdo con la cuál todas las partes del código se evalúan y se reemplazan por su output. Eso complica parametrizar el código, al desaparecer las comillas desaparece la forma más obvia de identificar qué es una variable y qué es un vector.

## ¿Solución?

Para solucionarlo a partir de la versión 0.7 `dplyr` utiliza su propio esquema de evaluación no estándar (NSE) llamado `tidyeval`. En apretada síntesis, introduce las funciones `enquo` y `enquos` y los operadores `!!` y `!!!` indicar que expresiones deben ser evaluadas de qué manera.

`!!` sirve para forzar a `dplyr` a evaluar una expresión (por ejemplo, uno o más nombres de columna provisto por el usuario/a) dentro de una función. `!!!` sirve para evaluar más una expresión, que generalmente se recoge en la llamada a la función con los `...` en los que pasamos un número arbitrario de argumentos separados por comas. Para que estos operadores funcionen primero tenemos que convertir a esos argumentos en un tipo especial de objetos llamados `quousures`.

El `tidyeval` es una caja de pandora y las cosas se complican rápido. Hay muchas funciones parecidas que se usan para extraer nombres, caracteres encomillados, etc.

> Es **muy** recomendable usar este esquema de evaluación dentro una función que estemos definiendo y nunca usarlo en el entorno global. Si en el entorno en el que estemos trabajando ya existe un nombre con el valor que queremos pasar a `enquo` la función va a "enquotar" (?) ese nombre ya existente y ese objeto de manera silenciosa. Por ejemplo, podríamos querer "enquotar"  el nombre `mpg` para indicar esa columna en el data set `mtcars`, pero al existir otro dataset que se llama `mpg`, `enquo` va a enquotar el tibble `mpg` y capturar la expresión `^tibble`. Dentro de la definición de una función no vamos a tener este problema.

## Ejemplos con `mtcars`

Un par de ejemplos, adaptados de la viñeta de programación con `dplyr`

### Función para calcular la media de una variable

```
media_parametrizada <- function(df, columna){
  vars_col <- enquo(columna)             #Capturo la expresión como quosure
  df %>% 
    summarise(media = mean(!!vars_col))  #!! evalúa vars_col y reemplaza el argumento de mean por la expresión capturada previamente
}

media_parametrizada(mtcars, mpg)
media_parametrizada(mtcars, mpg, wt) #Error!
```

### Función para calcular la media de un número arbitrario de variables

```
media_multiple_parametrizada <- function(df, ...){
  vars_cols <- enquos(...)
  df %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(!!!vars_cols), mean) # !!! evalúa vars_cols y lo pasa a vars como una lista
}

media_multiple_parametrizada(mtcars, mpg, wt)
```

### `group_by` con múltiples agrupamientos

```
media_agrupada <- function(df, variable, ...){
  grupos <- enquos(...)
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!!grupos) %>% 
    summarise(media = mean(!!variable))
}

media_agrupada(mtcars, mpg, am, gear, vs)
```

## Pasar una función arbitraria

```
arbitraria <- function(df, variable, función){
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  df %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(!!variable), función)
}
# No es necesario enquotar, por algún motivo la evalúa bien de manera directa. 
arbitraria (mtcars, mpg, median)
```